# Polymer - Paper-slider - Customizing paper-input

Tags: polymer

I am trying to customize paper-slider element. What I would like to do it is to add a prefix to the paper-input element created aside the slider.

I have tried the following code but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
<paper-slider min="0"  max="12"  value="1"   editable="true" pin="true" step="1" snaps="true">
   <div prefix>$</div>
</paper-slider>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this is supported. You can fork the element and customize it.

Comment: Thanks. That's always a possibility!